# Проблема с псевдоклассом hover

Tags: hover, padding

Пытаюсь создать hover эффект на странице.Суть такова - при наведении курсора на ссылку,фон позади нее должен стать черным с внутренними отступами в 10 пикселей с каждой стороны.Все работает,но при наведении курсора на ссылку,между ней и другими ссылками создается отступ.Как сделать так,чтобы не создавалось отступа между ссылками,когда наводишь на них курсор?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или сделать padding изначально с прозрачным фоном или подкладывать цветную подложку из псевдоэлемента с абсолютным позиционированием. Выложите код нормально, как код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте отступы изначально, при hover меняйте только фон

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</nav>
```